# Filter out null values resulting from window function lag() in SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Example query:

```
SELECT *, 
       lag(sum(sales), 1) OVER(PARTITION BY department
       ORDER BY date ASC) AS end_date_sales
FROM revenue
GROUP BY department, date;
```

I want to show only the rows where `end_date` is not `NULL`.

Is there a clause used specifically for these cases? `WHERE` or `HAVING` does not allow aggregate or window function cases.

Comment: . . Your query does not make sense.  You have `sum()` with no `group by`.  You are summing sales and calling it `end_date`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff ah yes, edited it, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method uses a subquery:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM (SELECT r. *, 
             LAG(sum(sales), 1) OVER (ORDER BY date ASC) AS end_date
      FROM revenue r
     ) r
WHERE end_date IS NOT NULL;
```

That said, I don't think the query is correct as you have written it.  I would assume that you want something like this:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM (SELECT r. *, 
             LEAD(end_date, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY ? ORDER BY date ASC) AS end_date
      FROM revenue r
     ) r
WHERE end_date IS NOT NULL;
```

Where `?` is a column such as the customer id.

Comment: is there another method besides wrapping the results in a subquery?

Comment: You can check the below answer which will work without sub query.

Comment: @Snow . . . I would suggest that you ask a *new* question with sample data, desired results, and a sensible query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select * from (select distinct *,SUM(sales) OVER (PARTITION BY dept) from test)t 
where t.date in(select max(date) from test group by dept)
order by date,dept;
```

And one more simpler way without sub query

```
SELECT distinct dept,MAX(date) OVER (PARTITION BY dept),
SUM(sales) OVER (PARTITION BY dept) 
FROM test;
```